# WinForms TreeView

Tags: winforms, treeview, drag-and-drop

I am looking for a WinForms treeview control with following requirements:

- Should be not so hard to write code for it (most tree/list combinations are way too complicated)
- Should have some sort of easy drag and drop capabilities (including a vista-explorer style drop marker)
- Should be free or at least affordable
- Should provide some freedom of text/color/style/etc. of the treenodes (classic "outlook bold with blue numbers style)

Any ideas?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would recommend http://www.lidorsystems.com/ !

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting alternative is [TreeViewAdv](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewadv.aspx), as suggested in another thread.

[C# replacement for standard Treeview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581985/c-replacement-for-standard-treeview)

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard WinForms' treeview control will do everything on your list. I don't know what the second item refers to as I've not used Vista. It's declared as `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` and is available in VS200*'s form designer. I can't think of any simpler way of doing tree views.

Comment: I'm not really happy with the standard winforms control - that's why I asked the question in the first place. Implementing drag&drop with a nice drop marker is really painful in the standard control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [SandGrid](http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sandgrid/) by Divelements. I use it for all my ListViews and TreeViews. It even supports both at the same time (a TreeView with columns). I find it easy to use and very fast.