# C# replacement for standard Treeview?

Tags: c#, treeview

I'd like to find a replacement for provided System.Windows.Form.Treeview. I need the following improvements :

- Multiple selection of items
- Better performance (performance of standard widget is simply awful, in particular when adding a long list of items)
- Scrolling while drag and dropping an item inside the treeview widget

I may be forgetting some, but these are quite important. Since i already have a software that makes use of the standard Treeview, I will take in consideration API differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an open source alternative, [TreeViewAdv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/) is very good.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I see that the latest release of TreeViewAdv goes back 18 months or so. Is it unmaintained or just really stable ?

Comment: The latest version is the last one I used and it was stable for me. Enjoy (:

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewadv.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) is another Open Source possibility.